# Problema con interfaz y mongodb en angular

Tags: angular, mongodb

Estoy trabajando con Angular y MongoDB. Tengo un problema que es el siguiente.
Tengo una interfaz visual que mediante un boton levanta un modal (de material desing) y en el ngOnInit del modal hago una llamada a mongodb para pedir una lista y mostrar los elementos en el modal pero pasa que a veces el modal sale en blanco como que la lista esta vacia y no muestra los elementos. A que se debe esto? Tengo que usar algun observer o algo? Gracias por su tiempo.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getIngredients();
    this.getPlates();
    this.idPlate_cantUntrue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('idPlate_cantUntrue'));
  }

getPlates() {
    this.plates = [];
    this.platesService.getPlates()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.plates = res as Plate[];
        //Aqui puse un async await para esperar por el metodo isAvailable, si no funciona introducir el código aquí
        //usare un observer.
        this.plates.forEach(async plate => {
          plate.available = await this.thirdPartyMethodsService.isAvailabe(plate, this.allIngredients);
          plate.cantUntrue = this.getCantUntrueById(plate._id);
          this.calculateCant(plate).subscribe(res => {
            this.platesService.updatePlate(plate).subscribe();
          });
        });
        this.getAvailablePlate();
      });
  }
```

Creo qu el error esta en que invoco el metodo getIngredients() se ejecuta de manera independiente de getPlates() y getPlates() depende de los resultados de getIngredientes(). Diganme si estoy en lo correcto.

Comment: Hola, en tu código no veo nada relacionado con MongoDB, por lo tanto te sugiero que no coloques dicha etiqueta. En cuanto a tu duda, sin conocer exactamente lo que hace el método `getIngredients()` y cómo se relaciona con `getPlates()` va a ser un poco difícil ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: plateServices es una instancia de un servicio que consume de un api rest sobre MongoDB y el metodo getIngredient() solamente devuelve una lista de todos los ingredientes. Los dos metodos getIngredients() y getPlates() llaman a sus servicios correspondientes para hacer la consulta a MongoDB. No puse los codigos porque seria demasiado extenso. Haciendo esta pregunta aqui me di cuenta de lo que puse anteriormente que es que getIngredients() se ejecuta en paralelo con getPlate() y getPlate() necesita si o si que getIngredients() finalize completamente. Disculpen las molestias y gracias.